# Is it possible to find a condition P so that f is bounded iff f' has P?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let's consider a differentiable function f:**R**->**R**, whose derivative is f'.

Is it possible to find a set of properties P so that f is bounded if and only if f' respects P? If so, do you know a theorem which states exactly who is P?

What I was able to find required more properties for f and f', meaning a loss of generality. For instance, if f' is strictly positive and f is bounded, then f' tends to 0.

I know f' is not necessarrily bounded, though that doesn't help much.

Comment: Well, there's the trivial answer: "has a bounded antiderivative." This is only worth mentioning because it *fails* if we allow functions with disconnected domain: if the domain has infinitely many connected components, then some antiderivatives of $f'$ will be unbounded even if some are bounded, and if those infinite connected components are each *compact* (= closed and bounded) then in fact $f'$ will have both bounded and unbounded antiderivatives regardless of what $f$ is. So if we allow disconnected domains then $f'$ alone does *not* determine the boundedness of $f$.